# Are there any tools to revolve a solid on an axis without creating copies?

Tags: cad, autodesk-inventor

[image: CAD Model]

I am using Autodesk Inventor Professional 2023 for a robotics assembly.  I can export the assembly in the picture as a .ipt file and revolve it in a pattern with x repetitions, spread out radially from the axis by n degrees.  This creates something close to what I'm looking to achieve, but has millions of polygons.  The purpose of this is to create a 3D zone where I know I cannot place things.  It should be the revolution of a part around an axis, equivalent to a infinite number of parts rotated equally around the axis. It could be described as a 2D enclosed polygon, revolved 360 degrees in 3D space.

Is there a separate free program I can use to perform this simplification, or a function in Inventor I can use?

Comment: @joojaa I tried that.  Revolving the part 20 times gives 1.5 million triangles in the stl.  I would want a smooth model as well...

Comment: well, yes. the envelope you want generated by projecting the outer edge of each component radially to same plane and revolving said component. What you can instead do is once you have a small segment of that pattern is take a cross section of it and simplify that. then revolve the cross section.

Comment: alternatively slice your object into many crosssections and boolean the outermost edge together.

Comment: Some applucations can bend your solids. if you bend it counter to your axis you can then project the edges onto a plane and revolve that.

Comment: Honestly? Just manually sketch around it with some straight lines that come close to the parts, and then revolve that - there's no need to overcomplicate this? How snug do you need it to be?

Comment: @JonathanRSwift well that works if all objects tangent on one projection. To be honest though solidworks can do this.